# Why does P1363 require RW signature with $0 ≤ s < n/2$?

Tags: signature, rabin-cryptosystem, p1363

I'm using an older copy of [P1363 Public Key Cryptography was used below](http://perso.telecom-paristech.fr/~guilley/recherche/cryptoprocesseurs/ieee/00891000.pdf). It may (or may not) reflect the current state of affairs.

P1363 has the following requirement in section 8.2.8 IFSP-RW, p. 45:

> ***Output***: The signature, which is an integer $s$ such that $0 ≤ s < n/2$

8.2.5 IFVP-RSA1 (p. 43) *does not* have the same requirement; but 8.2.6 IFSP-RSA2 (p. 44) *does* have the requirement.

Bernstein does not appear to discuss the requirement in [RSA signatures and Rabin–Williams signatures: the state of the art](http://cr.yp.to/sigs/rwsota-20080131.pdf).

What's the purpose of the restricted range on the signature? What threat does the requirement address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That practice of replacing the result of $y=x^d\bmod N$ (or $y=x^e\bmod N$) by $\hat y=\min(y,N-y)$ is also in [ISO/IEC 9796-2:2010 <sub><sup>(paywalled)</sup></sub>](https://webstore.iec.ch/preview/info_isoiec9796-2%7Bed3.0%7Den.pdf) and ancestors; I first met that in [[INCITS/ANSI]/ISO/IEC 9796:1991](http://webstore.ansi.org/RecordDetail.aspx?sku=INCITS%2FISO%2FIEC%209796-1991), also given in the [Handbook of Applied Cryptography](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/), see in particular [note 11.36](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/about/chap11.pdf#page=21). ISO/IEC 9796 was a broken and now [withdrawn](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=17658) signature scheme with message recovery based on RSA or RW, very different from ISO/IEC 9796-2.

With $e=2$ (or more generally even), $\;y^e\bmod N\;=\;(N-y)^e\bmod N$. Thus in a RW signature application, signatures $y$ and $N-y$ are equivalent. One rationale of using $\hat y$ is to choose a canonical signature among $y$ and $N-y$. **This allows the verifier to check that the signature is less than $N/2$, which prevents an adversary from turning a signature $y$ into a different but equally acceptable signature $N-y$** (some definition of signature security consider that a break).

With odd $e$ (RSA), there is no such security rationale. However we can still use $\hat y$ rather than $y$, if the low-order bit of $x$ is set to 0 by the padding scheme: if $\hat x=\hat y^e\bmod N$ turn out to be odd, the verifier uses $x=N-\hat x$ instead.

Whatever $e$, the maximum bit size of $\hat y$ is one less than the maximum bit size of $y$ (for arbitrary $x$). That size reduction, however small in proportion, allows:

- Direct re-encryption of $\hat y$ under textbook RSA using a different $N'$ of the same size as $N$, including when $N'<N$, which *can happen* when encryption and signature keys have modulus specified only by their common bit size (and *is bound to happen* for one of the two parties in some protocols between peers each using a single key for both encryption and signature, as in the [European Digital Tachograph](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/PDF/?uri=CELEX:01985R3821-20141101&rid=1#page=325)).
- Use of $N$ with $8k+1$ bits with convenient signatures of $k$ bytes; such $N$ have been extensively used in early public-key systems; as illustration, the example given in ISO/IEC 9791:1991, appendix B.1.1, has as 513-bit $N$.
  <sub>Incidentally, the leftmost 129 bits are all-zero except the leftmost one, which simplifies quotient estimation, perhaps at the price of somewhat easier factorization in particular with NFS, but that was not known at the time.</sub>

Comment: Thanks @fgrieu. This is going to take me some time to digest (sans the answer in bold text).